# Prevent OSX Sierra from restarting when left alone

Tags: osx, macintosh

If I leave my Mac on for the night because I forget to turn it off or I am trying to complete a security scan, it will always try and restart itself. Sometimes this is prevented by programs where I haven't saved my work, but other times it will completely restart.

I have turned auto update off (only automatically checking for updates) and also have my energy saver setting set so the machine will never even sleep.

Any help with this?